# Rails like database abstraction for Java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

I have recently been using rails for a web application, and so I have grown to quite like the way it makes dealing with a database very simple through Active Record. I am, therefore, wondering if there are any Java libraries that would make it equally simple to deal with the database by hiding away issue of writing SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at: [activejdbc](http://javalite.io/activejdbc)? It's an implementation of the Active Record pattern in Java, and obviously inspired by RoR.

Comment: Wow, this is ideal! Is it possible to use it without Maven, or should I go read a bunch of maven tutorials now?

Comment: If you're not using Maven you can grab it from here: http://ipsolutionsdev.com/snapshots/activejdbc/

Comment: for people to use ActiveJDBC without Maven, here is a page with instructions: http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/wiki/Instrumentation

Comment: The links above point to the older locations. This is a current location: http://javalite.io/

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an excellent ORM that generally serves this purpose:

http://www.hibernate.org/

You can build things like GenericDAOs that allow you to easily manage all objects the same way:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects

so that you can get basic CRUD capabilities very quickly for anything in your model, but still allows you to configure business logic particular DAO as needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Grails](http://www.grails.org/)
2. [Spring ROO](http://www.springsource.org/roo)
3. [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)

Are 3 java application frameworks who seem to share some similar scaffolding capabilities that was popularized with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

there is also ActiveWeb - a Rails-like Java web framework: http://code.google.com/p/activeweb/